# extends MapView doesn't work

Tags: android, android-mapview

I'm trying to extend the MapView Class to override the dispatchDraw() method

eclipse doesn't give me errors, however when I run the application on the emulator I get the error "**the application has stopped unexpectedly**"

this is the code for the class

```
public class HelloMapView extends MapView{

 public HelloMapView(Context context, String apiKey) {
        super(context, apiKey);
    }

    public HelloMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public HelloMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    }
```

}

here is it the code on the MapActivity

```
HelloMapView mapView;
..
..
mapView = (HelloMapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
..
..
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Provide your log output.

Comment: Also, please provide your layout file for HelloMapView. Are you instantiating a HelloMapView or Google's MapView in the layout? We really need the logcat dump. The error you quoted in the emulator is just the default unhandled exception handler

Answer (score 0):

Are you shure that you set the build to Google APIs instead of Android X.X?
Also you should look if you have the permissions, remember that the Google Maps uses internet.

If you already tryed all out be shure that you have in your manifest the

```
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" android:required="true"></uses-library>
```